# Swift get UIImage inside UIView programmatically

Tags: swift

I have an StackView with some UIViews inside, and that UIViews have an UIImage inside.

I want to get the imageViews programmatically, but with .subviews i get an array of UIViews and i can't parse them to UIImageViews.

This is my code:

```
for myView in myStackView.subviews {

    (myView.subviews.first as UIImage).layer?.cornerRadius = 20 //Can't parse it 

    print(myView.subviews) //getting UIView array
}
```

Comment: You need a `UIImageView` to present a `UIImage`

Comment: @MattiaRighetti Yes, i had to use UIImageView instead UIImage, thx

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple subviews and you want to access a specific view an efficient way is to assign a **tag**, either in the Storyboard or even in code.

Then you can access the view directly

```
let imageViewWithTag100 = myView.viewWithTag(100) as! UIImageView
```